# Change page orientation for a specific WordPress page

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, screen-orientation

I want to change the orientation to landscape for a specific page on mobile devices. Here is my code, which is not working. 
What is wrong with it?

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .page-id-1294 #change_orien html {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I see your HTML? Else send me the link.

Comment: @ManojKumar: I am using this theme: https://mageewp.com/onetone-theme.html

Comment: Hmmm. The theme does not help that much. Your site could have been customized afterward. Let me know the live version of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can inform the user he has to change orientation and hide the screen.
Then sense the orientation change and reload the page.

The following code should be placed at the end of the template of your page or in the footer.

This will reload the hidden page when the user rotates the device.

```
jQuery(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

This is to inform the user he should rotate the device, it hides the content when the page is in portrait state.
You should confirm that the ".content" is the right selector on your page.

```
if(screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth){
    jQuery( ".content" ).css( "display", "none" );
    var newLine = "\r\n"
    var msg = "Please use Landscape!"
    msg += newLine;
    msg += "(Turn your phone 90 degrees)";
    msg += newLine;
    msg += "and wait a second,";    
    msg += newLine;
    msg += "for the page to reload.";   
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code you are looking for a class, with an id in it, which has the html element in it. I don't think that this is what your html markup looks like. You need to get the class or id of your html / body tag and only target this in CSS.

So please take a look at your html markup, I think you should have the class in the body element, this would be the most common way.

`.page-id-1294 { /* your styles */ }`

---

Alternatively there also is a way to lock the orientation of your page with javascript. This way you wouldn't need to rotate the page back via css.

Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock

In javascript you can get the current orientation and save it to a variable. Then you can lock it:

`var screenOrientation = window.screen.orientation;`

`screenOrientation.lock("portrait");`

You could put this inside `<script> </script>` in your footer.php.

Comment: If I want to choose the media type, as I searched, it should be @media screen {.page-id-1294 {/* the style*/}}. Right?

Comment: Yes right (with "orientation: portrait" also, not only screen, I think you know), if the .page-id-1294 is the class of your body.

Comment: ´page-id.1294´ is the id of the target page

Comment: An CSS ID can not have a dot inside. You are misunderstand some basic points: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp  Can you provide a link to your page, or find out what really is the css id of your page? Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the info. What I am trying is something like: https://kriesi.at/support/topic/media-queries-5/#post-1059313

Comment: If you know the name of your id, instead of `.page-id-1294 #change_orien html {... ` you have got to use `#page-id-1294`  . The `#` is the css selector for IDs. Your code cannot not be applied if you are not targeting the right id of the element.